Are there any naturally preserved corpses that were not in fortuitous circumstances that are not considered saints by the Christian religion?
A question on the Christianity SE sparked this question.
"Are there any naturally preserved corpses" that were not in "fortuitous circumstances" that are not considered "Saints" by the Christian Religion.
By naturally preserved I mean that humans usually decay within a decade or so, so any remains that still have "skin" or other soft tissues are valid if they should have been dust already.
I'm not asking if there are naturally preserved "bog bodies" or "mummies", no "ice bodies" (such as the ice maiden), no "saltmen", "ginger" was in contact with sand, All of that would be a "fortuitous circumstances"
I'm interested in any people who were "tossed in a wooden box" or "thrown into the tomb" or any other simple "burial ritual" that wouldn't be a major benefit for preservation. So that means without "plastination" or other preservation methods intended to keep human remains in good condition for unnaturally long periods of time.
Funeral home style embalming would be acceptable however, as it only intends to preserve the body for a very short period of time. So if someone was found after simple embalming after half a century, it would be an example.
Any examples during the timeframe of the last 2000 years or so would be of interest.

Taphonomy shouldn't really be needed for this one, though if there is an example of oddly preserved bones where there shouldn't be anything remaining (that is without good circumstances), I'd be interested as well.

The best example that seems to fulfill these conditions is "Rosalia Lombardo" the sleeping beauty. Who was buried in catacombs in a coffin, after simple embalming. Not ideal but not bad preservation chances.
But I'm looking for others.

So you're looking for something that confirms the existence of supernatural events.

I'm tempted to think that your definition of "fortuitous circumstances" will rule out any examples.

I literally gave an example that fulfilled the definition. Please read the full question.

@Wyrsa Rosalia Lombardo has been literally embalmed, so it's not an example that would fulfill your definition.

@DevSolar I was unaware that she was embalmed before she was discovered. Drat. I will adjust the question.

Because I followed the link, and so others don't have to, I will reproduce the second sentence of the Wikipedia article on Rosalia Lombardo here: "Rosalia's father, Mario Lombardo, grieving her death, asked Alfredo Salafia, an embalmer, to preserve her remains."

is Lenin a good example? it seems to me the same as your "Rosalia Lombardo" sample (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenin%27s_Mausoleum#Preserving_the_body )

@phoog I was still adjusting the question, I realize I was unclear. Embalming was too broad, I am looking for people who are not being "intentionally preserved for decades/centuries/eternity"

@DanM Unfortunately not, it starts as a normal embalming but then his body was then shortly afterwards intentionally attempted to be preserved "indefinitely" so while it is cool science, it is not what I'm looking for.

@Wyrsa embalming isn't used exactly to prepare body to be "intentionally preserved for decades/centuries/eternity"?

@DanM again, correct... I took some time to find the proper word, though I believe my intent was clear as there is already an answer that skipped preservatives at all.

On a side note, I will gladly correct the question to be acceptable. As History.SE seemed like the only proper SE site for this question. If someone can explain what was wrong. I'm not looking for proof of supernatural events, I'm seeking facts and googling wasn't working.

@Wyrsa I don't understand how the answer provided is not a "fortuitous circumstances" as stated in your question. The comments are tentative to understand the question - given that preserving of the body is a "fortuitous circumstances" (ice, sand, or unknown - like in the answer) or is a "wanted circumstance" (embalming, and the use of preservatives).

One problem with this question is that it is 'fishing'. You are looking for examples- this has been discussed often in Meta, it becomes more of a discussion (see how many comments just to clarify the 'special conditions' to qualify answers). History questions should have a single authoritative answer.

@justCal Thank you! You're the first person to actually point out something in a directly constructive way. I will see if I can fix it later today.

@DanM I will be rewriting the question. I'm looking for preserved remains, not intentionally preserved for a long period of time. I realize that asking for a "list" is deeply frustrating for SE websites.

Knight Kahlbutz in Germany seems to be an example. Note however that he lived and died in a Lutheran area of Germany and Lutherans are not really into saints.

Thanks for this answer (instead of debating the question) this is indeed an example of what I am looking for. It is actually better then the example I found. And even fulfills the a very strict "no preservation methods used" aspect (which many thought would exclude any possible answer) Thank you! I'm still looking for more though. :)

@Wyrsa - Of course his body was effectively mummified as well, just likely not entirely on purpose. His casket was hermetically sealed, and they believe the circumstances of his death effectively drained him of much of his blood, so his corpse started out far dryer than is typical. The "no mummification" stipulation arguably can only exist if you don't fully understand what mummification is. Basically, if was well preserved, it was mummified by definition. Any human intentionality in its circumstances is a spectrum, not a bright line.

@T.E.D. My question is mostly based on intent, and the avoidance of "freak accidents" like tar pits, frozen tundras, or such. In that case "mummification" in my question is based on the intentional act of preservation.

Yes, there are.
On German cemeteries, we often have the problem of "Wachsleichen" (wax corpses) - corpses that are buried in a coffin, without any enbalming or other modifications, but cannot decay because the soil they are in is wet and loamy. And no, these are no bog bodies - this may even happen if you have a loamy soil and the grave is watered too often.
In such an environment, corpses often do not decay, but develop adipocere instead, which preserves them.
There is some information on this in the German Wikipedia:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wachsleiche

I'd imagine that the "wet and loamy" soil will count as fortuitous circumstances and therefore these will not be valid.

A good example, that I should have known about. This is definitely unintentional and is basically a box tossed into the ground. Thank you. @SteveBird a comment for the sake of commenting on my intent is not really helpful to improving the question or answer.
